# How to get previous exact date in moment.js?

Tags: javascript

I need to get "previous August, 1" date using moment.js; as there's no "previous" method in it, how to do this?

Comment: please explain in detail what you want to get by "previous date"  ?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Previous means last year August 1 Day you need or else?

Comment: So what have you tried? What isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there's nothing in the moment api for this (yet). There was some chatter about doing something similar on a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2522) a while back.

So you'll probably need to do it yourself.

Last August is either this year, if it's after August or last year if it's before. You can simply test this and act accordingly. So last August is 2017:

```js
let aug = moment("08-01", "MM-DD")
let lastAug = aug < moment() ? aug : aug.subtract(1, 'years')
console.log("Last August: ", lastAug.format("dddd DD-MM-YYYY"))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Last February, however, is 2018.

```js
  let feb = moment("02-01", "MM-DD")
  let lastfeb = feb < moment() ? feb : feb.subtract(1, 'years')
  console.log("Last February: ", lastfeb.format("dddd DD-MM-YYYY"))
```

```html
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `subtract()` method of momentjs

```js
var now = moment().format("dddd DD-MM-YYYY");
var  previous = moment().subtract(1, 'years').format("dddd DD-MM-YYYY");
     

  document.write(now+"<br/>"+previous);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How does this help OP find _"previous August 1"_?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will find *the first august this year*. If the day has not occured yet, then it will return *the first august of the previous year*.

```js
var thisYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();    
var lastAugust = new Date("8/1/" + thisYear);
if(moment() < lastAugust)
    lastAugust = new Date("8/1/" + (thisYear - 1));

var result = moment(lastAugust.valueOf()).format("dddd DD-MM-YYYY");

document.write(result);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```